# Avoid duplicate data in SQLite3 with a covering index

Tags: optimization, sqlite

In our company we have a rather big SQLite3 database with, let's say, some points of interest (POI). The database is created once, and used in read-only mode in a mobile user application.

POI have names that can contain several words and letters with diacritics. To perform a quick search of POI in the application, there is an additional table with single uppercase ASCII words and the corresponding ID in the main table. And there is a *covering index*. The database looks like this (simplified) :

```
CREATE TABLE poi(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, attributes TEXT);
CREATE TABLE poi_search (word TEXT, poi_id INTEGER);
CREATE INDEX poi_search_idx ON poi_search(word, poi_id);
```

Then, you can query for POI whose name contain `"FOO"` with a request like that:

```
SELECT * from poi INNER JOIN poi_search ON poi.id=poi_search.poi_id 
   WHERE poi_search.word < 'FOO' AND poi_search.word < 'FOP';
```

The query is very quick and uses a *covering index*, so it doesn't need to access the `poi_search` table at all:

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * from poi INNER JOIN poi_search ON poi.id=poi_search.poi_id WHERE poi_search.word < 'FOO' AND poi_search.word < 'FOP';
0|0|1|SEARCH TABLE poi_search USING COVERING INDEX poi_search_idx (word<?)
0|1|0|SEARCH TABLE poi USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
```

I just realized that this is a big waste of space, since the covering index duplicates all the data of the index table. In the application, the table `poi_search` is in fact *never* used.

In there a way, even a tricky one, to remove or to truncate the `poi_search` table while keeping all data in the covering index ? I know that such a database will be in a incoherent state, so probably there is no way with the official API to do such a hack.

I don't care having a hacked version of SQLite3 for the production of the database; but the DB has to produce correct search values for the given request in a vanilla SQLite3 client.

Comment: "word [GLOB](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) 'FOO*'" would be simpler than two comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tricky way, or a hack, to do what you want.
You'll have to make do with the [documented way](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html), which is guaranteed to keep the database consistent:

```
CREATE TABLE poi_search (
    word TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    poi_id INTEGER
) WITHOUT ROWID;
-- no other index needed
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that SQLite3 had a support for tables without rowid, supporting a text column as primary index.